# python script to respond to subprocess prompts

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen

I have looked and looked and tried many different forms of opening a subprocess and writing a response to the prompts that come up once the process is open. What is the most basic way to call upon the 'chpass' process and answer the prompts accordingly, this is on Mac OS X server.

Every which way of opening the process results in the script not answering the prompt.

I tried variations of:

```
pc = Popen(['chpass',name],stdin=PIPE)
pc.communicate(oldpassword)
pc.write(oldpassword)
pc.stdin.write(oldpassword)
```

Likely I simply do not know how to use this properly, perhaps there is a very basic tutorial that has an example of running a process such as chpass bash command and being able to write commands to it.

Comment: I get a down-vote and not an explanation of why, talk about a hit and run-- let's try and be productive here. I literally sat down for over 2 hours working on this problem, searching almost a half dozen options and still getting no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `pexpect` module.

Example of usage:

```
 child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
 child.expect ('Password:')
 child.sendline (mypassword)
```

Of course instead of `scp` you must write the name of the command you run.

Comment: I have tried pexpect with no good results. The script ends up in a paused like state waiting for input, I end up control-C'ing it

Comment: That means that you specified incorrect `expect` string. In my example it is `Password:`. Please check the string.

Comment: The prompt reads: 'Changing account information for username.\nPassword for username: ' .. I added the newline so you can imagine what it would look like. Stumped by this one :-\

Comment: And what did youa add to `child.expect`?

Comment: A variation on both sentences, either as one expect method call and as two seperate calls. I also just tried the second sentence by itself.

Comment: pc = pexpect.run('chpass '+name)
exp  = "Changing account information for "+name+".\nPassword for "+name+":  "
pc.expect(exp)
pc.send(oldpassword)

Comment: try just `"Password for %s:" `. But you must be 100% sure that that is exactly what writes the server

Comment: it hangs just the same waiting for the proper expect i believe

Comment: using the .* wildcard in place of the username 'name' variable; this seemed to solve this issue, specifying anything else did not work with pexpect.